# Binding function to a button inside a Custom Widget from outside

Tags: kivy, custom-widgets, event-binding

I made this Widget:

```
<ImageButton>:
    source:''
    text:''
    release_fn: None
    Button:
        on_release: root.release_fn()
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 30
            size: self.parent.size
            pos: self.parent.pos
            orientation:'vertical'
            Image:
                id: img
                source: root.source
            Label:
                size_hint_y:.3
                text: root.text
```

Now I want to pass to it a function to be called when the button is released, but I can't figure out how to do it (and I couldn't find anything with the answer...)

The following gives me only a syntax error in the last line (the rest - and good working part - of the kivy file is omitted)

```
ImageButton:
    source: 'iconUsuario.png'
    text: 'Usuario'
    release_fn: print('HI!')


     print('HI!')
         ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out that it seemed not to be the best idea and I used a custom event:

```
class ImageButton(Widget):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(ImageButton,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_release')

    def on_release(self,*args):
        pass

    def callback(self,instance):
        self.dispatch('on_release')
        pass
```

kv file:

```
<ImageButton>:
    source:''
    text:''
    Button:
        on_release: root.callback(self)
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 30
            size: self.parent.size
            pos: self.parent.pos
            orientation:'vertical'
            Image:
                id: img
                source: root.source
            Label:
                size_hint_y:.3
                text: root.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't like using its print as a name for anything else for some reason. Try to run this:

```
def print():
    pass
def print:
    pass
```

always a `SyntaxError` at prin***t***. KV lang does basically this:

```
eval(print('bla'))
```

So, let's have a wrapper for the print. You probably won't use pure print anyway. Then you may notice the function returns `None`, that's because it's called with `on_release: root.release_fn()` as the first value `release_fn: something()` is just like a partial (and when you call `partial(func, arg)()` the function is really called).

That's why you need to import `functools.partial`, to do it one more time, so that the function is called at the desired place after the button is pressed, not immediately:

```
on_release: root.release_fn()
```

**Example:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """
#:import partial functools.partial
ImageButton:
    release_fn: partial(app.prints, 'bla')

<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>:
    source:''
    text:''
    release_fn: None
    Button:
        on_release: root.release_fn()
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        BoxLayout:
            padding: 30
            size: self.parent.size
            pos: self.parent.pos
            orientation:'vertical'
            Image:
                id: img
                source: root.source
            Label:
                size_hint_y:.3
                text: root.text
"""


class TestApp(App):
    def prints(self, value):
        print(value)

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @KeyWeeUsr. I i don't know about partial and I will study it. As you said, kv really gets the eval to its properties. I just aswered my own question. I was lacking about Custom Events. And this was the best for this case. Anyway, thanks again :)